# Convert list of numpy ndarray to multiple list of lists

Tags: python, list, numpy

I have an list of numpy.ndarray (5,6) (total size (5,6,5)) which i want to convert into 5 list of lists. each list should contain the information of each row, of each numpy.ndarray.

One way of doing this would be doing to manually, but this can become troublesome for bigger numpy.ndarrays, time consuming, so what how can i do this effectively?

example:

```
>>> import numpy
>>> a = numpy.zeros((6,5))
>>> b = numpy.ones((6,5))
>>> c = numpy.ones((6,5))*2
>>> d = [a,b,c]
>>> print d
[array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]]), array([[ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.]]), array([[ 2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.],
       [ 2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.],
       [ 2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.],
       [ 2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.],
       [ 2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.],
       [ 2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.]])]
>>> e = list(d)
>>> print e
[array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]]), array([[ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.]]), array([[ 2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.],
       [ 2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.],
       [ 2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.],
       [ 2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.],
       [ 2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.],
       [ 2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.]])]
# not wanted
>>> print e[0].tolist()
[[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]]
#wanted
>>> [[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [1,1,1,1,1], [2, 2, 2, 2, 2], ]
```

Comment: Did you try `.tolist()`?

Comment: that would convert the entire ndarray to an array.. I need to have list of the rows for each ndarray.
Basically.. something like a list of list of list.. 
Outer  (5,) middle (6,) last(5)

Comment: If `arr` is (5,6,5) shape, `list(arr)` should give a list of 5 (6,5) arrays.  `tolist()` converts it to all the way down - a list of lists of lists.  What shape should the lowest level array have?

Comment: `.tolist()` produces a list of 5 lists of lists, that's exactly what you asked for.

Comment: But the seperation is quite right.. list(arr)[0] should contain first row entries for all ndarrays in the list of ndarray, and not just the entries of the first ndarray.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`d` is a list of 3 arrays.  `list(d)` doesn't change anything.

`e = np.array(d)` will produce a (3,6,5), 3d array.

```
In [37]: e=np.array(d)
In [38]: e.shape
Out[38]: (3, 6, 5)
In [39]: e[:,0,:]
Out[39]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [2, 2, 2, 2, 2]])
In [40]: list(e[:,0,:])
Out[40]: [array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0]), array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1]), array([2, 2, 2, 2, 2])]
In [41]: e[:,0,:].tolist()
Out[41]: [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2, 2, 2]]
```